# How do i check the value of Array[x,y] quickly when debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arrays, debugging

When a breakpoint is hit, I could easily hover over a variable to see its current value. But when an array is present this becomes tricky (at least for me)

dsInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsApproved"]

There are few things that I could actually do in this scenario to quickly check the value.

1. Debug.WriteLine()
2. MessageBox (lame!)
3. Breakpoint -> When Hit -> Print a Message
4. Swim through the array to the find the position.

Are there any better methods to check the value of Array[x,y] quickly using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy expression you want to check (dsInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsApproved"]) and paste into 'Watch' window when debugging.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It most definitely helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can type in the variable name/expression `dsInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsApproved"]`
 into the Immediate window (Ctrl+I) while debugging.